# Python: Palindrome Equaton

Tags: python, palindrome

I need help filling in the blanks to make this function, which will check if a word is a palindrome, work:

```py
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    for ___:
        # Add any non-blank letters to the 
        # end of one string, and to the front
        # of the other string. 
        if ___:
            new_string = ___
            reverse_string = ___
    # Compare the strings
    if ___:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to you this webpage that **contains four (04) Algorithms to solve the palindrome problem**. The source code is in javaScript, but you can easily do same in (or translate to) Python.

Link : https://medium.com/better-programming/algorithms-101-palindromes-8a06ea97af86

What you trying to do is the **solution 1** in the previous proposed webpage.

Also, **Palindrome algorithm** is very well known, and there are a lot off documentaries on it, you can begin by this:

- [Palindrome on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/recursive-algorithms/a/using-recursion-to-determine-whether-a-word-is-a-palindrome)
- [Palindrome on coursera](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/program-code/palindrome-algorithm-1-zzQqs)
- [Palindrome on geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-check-string-palindrome-not/)

For general information, check the [wikipedia page on Palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome)

Good luck.

Comment: The link you added is about JavaScript, not Python

Comment: @JacobSánchez , yes indeed, I was going fast, and I was just focusing on the algorithms (to mention that there are several different ways that solve the Palindrome problem). I corrected the post, thank you for your relevant remark :)